# Why won't HttpPlatformHandler create log files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I can no longer create log files with ASP.NET RC1 and the HttpPlatformHandler.

This is the warning in the event log:

```
The description for Event ID 1004 from source HttpPlatformHandler cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

Warning: Could not create stdoutLogFile , ErrorCode = -2147024843.
```

Relevant Software versions:

- Microsoft Http Platform Handler 1.2
- Windows Server 2012 R12
- ASP.NET 5 RC1 application.

I've tried various values for the stdoutLogFile argument. I'm using the (poor) documenation from http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/httpplatformhandler/httpplatformhandler-configuration-reference

I've tried:

- \?c:\temp\wtlogs\
- c:\temp\wtlogs\
- no value (to try to log it into the "logs" directory that sites beside wwwroot and approot)

web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="..\approot\prod.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="\\?c:\temp\wtlogs\" startupTimeLimit="3600" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"></httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have the permissions set:
[image]

And the app pool is:

[image]

Comment: Can you try a few further things: (1) Specify an actual *file name*, e.g. `stdout.log`. (2) Use the default path which is `..\logs\stdout.log` (and as such logs into a folder parallel to the `wwwroot` and `approot` folders). (3) Can you try giving write permission to All users?

Comment: poke, i tried the full name, i gave full permissions to "Users". What worked is using the default path (..\logs\stdout.log). You should add that as an answer.

Comment: i have same problem,but already solved at [IISIntegration#45](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/45)

Answer (score 4):

This config is creating a log file in the 'c:\temp' folder.
You have to create first the 'c:\temp' folder.

```xml
 <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="c:\temp\" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
```

Comment: after create "logs" folder works, we had to make all of the folder tree! iis will make files not folders

Answer (score 0):

You should use a file name as `stdoutLogFile` value, try using `c:\temp\wtlogs\stdout.log`

Comment: What is event log message when you try with file name?

Comment: Same as in my original question. They only thing I could get to work was using ..\logs\stdout.log.

Comment: Wait 2147024843 is "The network path could not be found", it shouldn't throw this error on local paths. and access denied is 2147024891. Is your web application directory on network location?